# Can github pages send http requests to an external server?

Tags: angular, deployment, httprequest, github-pages

I have recently developed an angular app in which I had linked to a backend django rest api. Then I used gh-pages to deploy it. But it doesn't even show up (it's a blank page).
I know github only hosts static pages and cannot handle post/get requests. But I assume this is only from an external server to github not the other way around. Or am I wrong?

Thanks for help.

**Edit:**

[There is the link to the github pages for the project](https://moctardiallo.github.io/samaschool/)

Comment: can you share the link for github pages you hosted

Comment: @PardeepJain sorry didn't see your comment: i have edited the question to add the link. I still don't have an answer. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the base url in `index.html` file. like below -

```
<base href="./">
```

It is an HTML tag which is used to specify the root of the resources.
Angular 2 adds base href in index.html to tell router how to compose navigation URL's for respurces.

By default base URL is set as (/) or root.

Comment: Worked. Can you briefly explain to me what was going on?

Comment: @mctrjalloh added explanation